# How I can play projects that I downloaded from site android developer

Tags: android

I am trying to work on the projects that I was downloded by SDK but it not work when I open it with eclips, I open it by import>and I select the folder project
the error appear in Emulator as in picture

[image]

What I do to run thats projects? please any one help me

Comment: softkeyboard is already installed in your emulator as the default keyboard. Normally if you get such error , you need to uninstall that app, and again running will solve this. But here Softkeyboard is system app and cannot be uninstalled I think. Try with some other example. OR change the package names in your code,and run it as a different app.

Comment: edited the post on your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your emulator already contains softketboard with certain signatures.

Un-install that and your project will run

[Check out this link](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/HowTo)

**Edit:-**

Keep in mind that softKeyboard sample come preinstalled in every emulator. So if you want to test this in a emulator, you have to uninstall the preinstalled version first. Either `run adb uninstall com.example.android.softkeyboard` from the command line of your OS or uninstall the examples via Preferences -> Applications in the emulator itself.

Comment: thanks, but How I can Un-install softketboard that already installed in my Emulator, if I cant that: How I do softketboard application with softketboard system and it work as system app not as activaty individual

Comment: If this solves your problem mark this answer as correct for others to benifit

Comment: the reason was in name of application, I changed it and it woeked

Comment: my account is blocked,and I cant answer again, How I can to unbloced my account, please help me